# How to change the background color of the button to a specific colour?

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I want the color to be a specific color such as #ff6f00 and simply black or white.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addnote"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"

            android:background="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Button element and set the background to a selectable to achieve the best results.

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/addnote"
   android:layout_width="65dp"
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_margin="15dp"
   android:layout_height="65dp"
   android:background="@drawable/custom_selector" />
```

Add a the file "custom_selector.xml" in your `drawable` folder.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- disable state. -->
<item android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#ebe5df"/>
        <stroke android:color="#e4d6d0" android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<!--released state. -->
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#63b8ff"/>
        <stroke android:color="#4580b2" android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<!--pressed state. -->
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#63b8ff"/>
        <stroke android:color="#c0e2ff" android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Just set the colors of each of the states as you like.

Comment: Can you please write the suitable code for it . I am just a beginner.

Comment: You need to use this website to get the hexa value of colour with matching and contrast as wel (https://www.color-hex.com/)